# XMLHttpRequest get data while PHP script is running

Tags: javascript, php, html, xmlhttprequest

I am trying to poll a PHP page for an updated $val variable value, but for some reason it doesn't want to show anything on the calling html page

PHP (generator.php) script:

```
<?php

header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
function output($val)
{
echo $val;


    flush();
    ob_flush();
    usleep(500000);
}
output('Begin... (counting to 10)');
for( $i = 0 ; $i < 10 ; $i++ )
{
    output($i+1);
}
output('End...');

?>
```

HTML page:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">

function generate(){

    try {
        xmlhttp = window.XMLHttpRequest ? new XMLHttpRequest() : new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    } catch(e) {
    }

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = refreshwait;
    xmlhttp.open('GET', './generator.php', true);
    xmlhttp.send('null');

}

function refreshwait() {

    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4){

        if(xmlhttp.status == 200){

            var code = 'Finished';
            document.getElementById('view_area').innerHTML = code;  
        }

    }else{

        document.getElementById("view_area").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;          
        refreshwait();
    }

}

</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="a_form">
<form id="aform">
<input name="Generate" onClick="generate()" type="button" value="Generate Fresh File" />
</form>
</div>
<div id="view_area"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

What am I doing wrong? I am expecting to see a count from 1 to 10 appear on the html page as the php is running.

Comment: Does it work if you remove the calls to flush and ob_flush?

Comment: try to full path or url of file and alert result in success state

Comment: code is working try to check file path xmlhttp.open('GET', './generator.php', true);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can think of four potential issues:

1. Some servers (SAPIs) feature internal output buffering, typically to a size of 4Kb. This is because sending "chunks" of this size is generally more efficient than sending many smaller pieces.
2. Some browsers will read chunks of a certain size (again, typically 4Kb) before rendering them to the document. This again improves performance by not re-rendering the page every time a few bytes happen to show up in the network stream.
3. Some browsers (particularly older IE, can't remember which version) do not allow access to `responseText` until the `readyState` is `4`. Obviously this is a limitation, and it has been removed in newer browsers, but it's still a possible problem.
4. EDIT: Some browsers require you to define `onreadystatechange` *after* calling `.open()`. This is to allow reuse of `XMLHttpRequest` objects. Calling `.open` effectively "resets" the object.

Possible solution: Assuming the problem is 1 or 2, rather than 3 or 4, then you can try outputting `echo $val.str_repeat(" ",5000);` to try and circumvent the output buffering. Obviously this will bloat your bandwidth, but the result should look the same (because spaces are collapsed in HTML)

Comment: You are right, output buffering is set beyond what was being output by the php script. Thanks for that, it would've taken me ages to figure it out myself.

Comment: I thought "flush" in php would take care of that problem. Is there another way to fix this without using htaccess or altering php.ini?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of, sorry. HTTP isn't really designed for that kind of thing.